# Borders of a matrix are not well placed

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\colorlet{mlightgray}{gray!20}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={cell, minimum width=1cm, fill=mlightgray}},
  column 2/.style = {nodes={cell, minimum width=2cm}},
  column 3/.style = {nodes={cell, minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5, fill=mlightgray}},
  row 2/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}},
  row 3/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}},
  row 4/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}},
  ] 
  { & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & a & b \\
    2 & c & d \\
    3 & & e \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

It produces this matrix:

[image]

It seems that I have used all the solutions mentioned in other threads: `pgflinewidth` and `nodes={anchor=center}`... but the borders still don't overlap...

Don't understand why the library makes overlapping so hard, which is a quite obvious need... Could anyone help?

In addition, I just want to always make the first row and the first column have `mlightgray` as background color, is there a way to avoid from repeating `row .../.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}}` many times?

Moreover, unlike the rows, when I tried to put `minimum width=2` (instead of `2cm`) for the columns, it didn't work well. Why do I have to put the unit for that width?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `text height` and `text depth` keys so all nodes have the same size.

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\colorlet{mlightgray}{gray!20}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center,text height=2ex,text depth=0.25ex},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={cell, minimum width=1cm, fill=mlightgray}},
  column 2/.style = {nodes={cell, minimum width=2cm}},
  column 3/.style = {nodes={cell, minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5, fill=mlightgray}},
  row 2/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}},
  row 3/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}},
  row 4/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}},
  ] 
  { & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & a & b \\
    2 & c & d \\
    3 & & e \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The code can be further simplified:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\colorlet{mlightgray}{gray!20}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw=black}, nodes in empty cells]
  \matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={anchor=center,text height=2ex,text depth=0.25ex,cell},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=1cm, fill=mlightgray}},
  column 2/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  column 3/.style = {nodes={minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style={nodes={fill=mlightgray}},
  ] 
  { & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & a & b \\
    2 & c & d \\
    3 & & e \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer... But how did you determine the values of `text height` and `text depth`? I would like to put a text in the very center of a cell. I would the height of a cell is `0.5` and its width is `1` for the first column and `2` for the other columns...

Comment: @SoftTimur 1 and 2 what, centimetres, inches?

Comment: In other tikz environments without any specification I use numbers such as `1`, `2` ... So I guess in this case `1` = `1cm`?

Comment: @SoftTimur No. `minimum width` expects as value a length register (number + unit, as in `2cm` or `1in`) not just a number.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use

```
execute at begin cell=\strut,
execute at empty cell={\node{\strut};},
```

and delete `nodes in empty cells`. Further, by defining nodes as

```
nodes={cell,anchor=center,minimum width=2cm},
```

you can simplify further. Please note that when you use `minimum width` it expects a length parameter so you have to specify units like `1cm` or `1in` etc instead of simply `1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\colorlet{mlightgray}{gray!20}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[cell/.style={rectangle,draw}]
  \matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep =-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep = -\pgflinewidth,
  execute at begin cell=\strut,
  execute at empty cell={\node{\strut};},
  nodes={cell,anchor=center,minimum width=2cm},
  column 1/.style = {nodes={cell, minimum width=1cm, fill=mlightgray}},
%  column 2/.style = {nodes={cell, minimum width=2cm}},
%  column 3/.style = {nodes={cell, minimum width=2cm}},
  row 1/.style={nodes={cell, fill=mlightgray}},
  %row 2/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}},
%  row 3/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}},
%  row 4/.style={nodes={cell, minimum height=0.5}},
  ]
  { & 2 & 3 \\
    1 & a & b \\
    2 & c & d \\
    3 & & e \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you... I see your point... Do you know why I could not set `minimum width=2` (instead of `2cm`) for a column?

Comment: @SoftTimur It needs (being a length) units (cm or mm or in etc) not just number.